# how do i make big calculation in mysql

Tags: mysql

please elaborate the procedure to make this calculation

i have two table 
1.film
2.film_category

```
film
-------------------------------------------
film_id | replacement_cost | rental_rate 
      1 |               20 |         2.0 
      2 |               22 |         1.0 
      3 |               24 |         0.9 
      4 |               20 |         2.0 
      5 |               22 |         1.0 
      6 |               24 |         0.9 
      7 |               20 |         8.0 
      8 |               22 |         10  
      9 |               24 |         0.9 


film_category
-----------------------------
film_id | category_id 
      9 |           1 
     60 |           2 
     44 |           3 
      3 |           1 
     66 |           1 
     40 |          10
```

I want my output to show film categories having (average difference between the film replacement cost and the rental rate) > 15.
which is something like below

```
-----------------------------------------------
category_id | avg_difference_more_than_15
          1 |                        16.3
          2 |                        22.1
          2 |                        15.6
```

my code is given below but it is not working.
please correct me what is wrong in my code

```
select category_id
     , (AVG(sum(replacement_cost-rental_rate))"x" 
  from film
     , film_category 
 where film.film_id = film_category.film_id 
 GROUP 
    by category_id 
having x > 15
```

Comment: Define `is not working` .....

Comment: It's a pity your sample data only contains 1 category after join and group by

Comment: Yep, there's only one corresponding film. This is a pointless example.

Comment: And your expected output does not seem to derive from the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mubin the trick to this is creating a subquery to make it possible to get the average difference between the replacement cost and the rental rate by category id.

Here is what your query should look like:

```
SELECT `category_id`,
    AVG(`difference`) AS `avg_difference_more_than_15`
FROM (SELECT `fc`.`category_id`,
         `fc`.`film_id`,
         `f`.`replacement_cost`,
         `f`.`rental_rate`,
         `f`.`replacement_cost` - `f`.`rental_rate` AS `difference`
       FROM `film_category` AS `fc`
       JOIN `film` AS `f` ON `f`.`film_id` = `fc`.`film_id`
       GROUP BY `fc`.`category_id`, `fc`.`film_id`) AS `der`
 GROUP BY `category_id`
 HAVING AVG(`difference`) > 15
```

If this doesn't work for you please let me know along with some clarification as to why and I'll do my best to get you what you need.

Hope this helps!